# Embedly cards height customise?

Tags: embedly

Trying to customise the embedly cards height so all the embeded content is the same size. at the moment they come out different sizes, which messes with page layout. The links are dynamically created when users add links into the database.

```
<blockquote class="embedly-card" data-card-controls="0">
```

Is there a way to control the height of the content?

Edit:

I put a wrapper over the content to give me some sort of control. Doesnt look as well as I want, but its a temporary solution until the project gets redesigned.

```
#IframeWrapper{
width: 100%;
position: relative;
padding-bottom: 56.25%;
padding-top: 35px;
height: 0;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, no. Because of the unpredictable nature of the content inside the card, there is no option for fixed height.

You can restrict the width of the cards. data-card-width="400" will take card of this.

Comment: Yes I knew about the width. Bit annoyed they staff told me I could change he height after paying them money. 

My CSS solution gets the job 70% done. Fixes the layout but not looking as well as I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<center><div style="max-width:90%;min-height: 350px;border-style:outset;vertical-align:middle;"><a  data-card-controls="0" href="{param}" class="embedly-card">{param}</a></div></center>
```

Comment: please include why you using it in your answer, rather just code!